# Android App : How to Stop a running Time Counter after AsyncTask received data?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, runnable

I have following problem :

My Android App is communicating via WLAN with a raspberry pi 3. 
My Android App has a start button and a clear button and 2 textviews. 
When the start button is pressed, it creates a sound and after that it sends a string a to the pi and the app starts a time counter, that is displayed on one of the textviews.

When the light barrier(connected with Pi) has been crossed, the pi sends a string back(end time) and this string gets received by the AsyncTask in my CLIENT Class and displayed on the second textview. But the counter is still running and that's the problem. **In the moment the end time is received , i want the counter to be stopped.** I need a a way for my code that these two processes communicate with each other just to stop the counter. When i press the clear button i manage it to stop the counter. My last try, that is included in the code beneath, was to set a variable to 1 in a extra class when the end time is received (in the section "on post execute" i try to set the value to 1). And a fixed timer looks up for that value "all the time", and if this value is 1 the Time counter shall be stopped. I tried this and several things but never have came to a solution. And i tried to debug the last try but it did not work. So please if you have an idea how to tell the counter to stop

**The Class "Client" includes the implementation of the AsyncTask, that receives the end time and post it to the textview of the app. 
The MainActivity Class includes the process for the counter and the timer that asks for the value in the counter class.**

The Counter Class is there to set the variable (my try of a shared resource)

**Main Activity**

```
package com.client.androidsrc.client;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView timetext;
    TextView response;
    Button buttonConnect, buttonClear;

    public long startTime = 0L;

    public Handler customHandler = new Handler();

    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.run);

        buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
        buttonClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearButton);
        response = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.End_time);
        timetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Time);
        timetext.setText("00:00:00");

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.go);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mp.start();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(6000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                client myClient = new client(response);
                myClient.execute();

                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
                //client_send send = new client_send();
                //send.execute();

                new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        counter controller = new counter();
                        if(controller.stopper==1)
                        {
                            customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                            startTime = 0L;
                            timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
                            updatedTime = 0L;
                            timetext.setText("");
                        }
                    }
                }, 0, 50);
            }
        });


        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                startTime = 0L;
                timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
                updatedTime = 0L;
                timetext.setText("00:00:00");
            }
        });
    }

    public Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timetext.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };
}
```

**Client Class**

```
package com.client.androidsrc.client;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.widget.TextView;

/**
* Created by Florian on 26.11.2016.
*/

public class client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String response ;
    TextView textResponse;

    client( TextView textResponse) {
            dstAddress = "192.168.42.1";
            dstPort = 51717;
            this.textResponse = textResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            Socket socket = null;

            try {
                    socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                                    1024);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                    int bytesRead;

                    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    printStream.print("3");
                    //Log.d("Test","5 second test done");



                    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

             /*
                * notice: inputStream.read() will block if no data return
                */


                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            response = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");


                    }



            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            } finally {
                    if (socket != null) {
                            try {
                                    socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
            }
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            textResponse.setText(response);
            counter mycounter = new counter();
            mycounter.stop();
            super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

**Counter Class**

```
package com.client.androidsrc.client;

public class counter {

    public int stopper = 0;

    public void stop () {
        stopper = 1;
    }

    public void setback() {
        stopper = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create the `AsyncTask` class (Client) as an inner class in your `MainActivity` class. So, you will be able to access your `customHandler` object inside `onPostExecute` method to stop the timer.

Comment: Hallo Prerak, thank you for the answer. i will try it.

Comment: Thank you , that worked. What a simple solution...

Comment: Glad to hear that 